# Is masturbation itself a sin or are the lustful thoughts associated with masturbating?

Tags: scripture, enlightenment

Please provide direct quotes from texts please.

EDIT: I don't think this question is the same as another one in this forum because that question doesn't separate masturbation from lustful thoughts, whereas this one does.

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/34037/8735. In age of Kali, thoughts do not but action alone would cause sin. So just lustful thoughts won’t cause sin in Kali but if that thoughts led you to do actions (masturbate) then it will.